# Google share button -> Callback function not called

Tags: javascript, callback, share

Have read the google document, got my google share button up and running.
Now I would like to perform an action after a "share".

There is a parameter called 'onendinteraction' available to define a callback function to run.

For some reason, I cannot get this function to be called.

```
SiteLanguageName=$("#social-network").attr('lang');
SiteURL=$("#social-network").attr('href');

window.___gcfg = {
lang: SiteLanguageName,
parsetags: 'onload',
annotation:'none',
height: 24,
href:SiteURL,
onendinteraction: 'AfterShare'
};

(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();

function AfterShare(data) { alert('This is the result '+data.type); }
```

After the user click 'Share', no alert box pops up.
Maybe I'm missing something simple.

This can be seen here:

http://www.linguashop.com/welsh-to-english

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`onendinteraction` is not a variable in that object. They are attributes in the tag. For example:

```
<g:plus action="share" href="http://www.google.co.uk" onendinteraction="AfterShare" ...></g:plus>
```

Comment: Deif, thanks for the quick answer.  Tried your suggestion, but still not working. On www.linguashop.com/welsh-to-english you can see the button html.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You would need to post your new code in your question. Linking to your own site is not going to help as we cannot see the original code easily. Split your included code into the HTML part and the Javascript part.